# table header missing after search

Tags: html

I tried the answer to the following question: [Search Field on multiple indexes in a html table using java-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763643/search-field-on-multiple-indexes-in-a-html-table-using-java-script/46966784?noredirect=1#comment80883540_46966784)

It did work, but for some reason it keeps hiding the header after the function has run. Any advise?

```
 <style type="text/css">* {
      box-sizing: border-box;

    }

    input[type=text] {
        width: 230px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: white;
        background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
        text-align: center;
        background-position: 10px 10px; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;

          margin: 0 auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;



    }

    input[type=text]:focus {
        width: 100%;



    }

    #myTable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    #myTable th, #myTable td {

      text-align: left;
      padding: 12px;
    }

    #myTable tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    #myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;

    }
    </style>
    <p align="center"><font color="#124e72" face="Effra" size="7">Report Portal</font></p>

    <p style="text-align: center;"><input id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for reports.." title="Type in a name" type="text" /></p>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <table id="myTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="header">
                <th style="width:40%">Title</th>
                <th style="width:20%">Validation Status</th>
                <th style="width:20%">Report Type</th>
                <th style="width:10%">Open Report</th>
                <th style="width:10%">Info</th>
                <th style="display:none">Functional Owner</th>
                <th style="display:none">Developed In</th>
                <th style="display:none">Category</th>
                <th style="display:none">Validation Assessment</th>
                <th style="display:none">Implementation Plan</th>
                <th style="display:none">Implementation Report</th>
                <th style="display:none">Intended Use</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Scrap Report</td>
                <td>Validated</td>
                <td>Business Objects</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Open</a></td>
                <td>(i)</td>
                <td style="display:none">Ops</td>
                <td style="display:none">Spotfire</td>
                <td style="display:none">Scrap</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">The intended use of this report is to identify the Scrap Cost by Reason at manufacturing processing steps by part number and date range. This data could be used to determine where process improvements can be made; and used for PFMEA calculations and PRB decisions/documentation.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Training xReport</td>
                <td>Validated</td>
                <td>Business Objects</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Open</a></td>
                <td>(i)</td>
                <td style="display:none">Ops</td>
                <td style="display:none">Spotfire</td>
                <td style="display:none">Scrap</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">The intended use of this report is to identify the Scrap Cost by Reason at manufacturing processing steps by part number and date range. This data could be used to determine where process improvements can be made; and used for PFMEA calculations and PRB decisions/documentation.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rty Report</td>
                <td>Validated</td>
                <td>Business Objectszzz</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Open</a></td>
                <td>(i)</td>
                <td style="display:none">Ops</td>
                <td style="display:none">Spotfire</td>
                <td style="display:none">Scrap</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">kalam</td>
                <td style="display:none">The intended use of this report is to identify the Scrap Cost by Reason at manufacturing processing steps by part number and date range. This data could be used to determine where process improvements can be made; and used for PFMEA calculations and PRB decisions/documentation.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, ii;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            var tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            var found = false;
            for (ii = 0; ii < tds.length && !found; ii++) {
                if (tds[ii].textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            tr[i].style.display = found?"":"none";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: move your header row into a `<thead></thead>` instead of in `<tbody></tbody>`, the reason is that you are reloading the content in the table, thus overwriting your header row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is filtering every rows there is no need to filter header row

use **:not** selector to not select the header in search

```html
<style type="text/css">* {
      box-sizing: border-box;

    }

    input[type=text] {
        width: 230px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: white;
        background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
        text-align: center;
        background-position: 10px 10px; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;

          margin: 0 auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;



    }

    input[type=text]:focus {
        width: 100%;



    }

    #myTable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    #myTable th, #myTable td {

      text-align: left;
      padding: 12px;
    }

    #myTable tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    #myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;

    }
    </style>
    <p align="center"><font color="#124e72" face="Effra" size="7">Report Portal</font></p>

    <p style="text-align: center;"><input id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for reports.." title="Type in a name" type="text" /></p>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <table id="myTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="header">
                <th style="width:40%">Title</th>
                <th style="width:20%">Validation Status</th>
                <th style="width:20%">Report Type</th>
                <th style="width:10%">Open Report</th>
                <th style="width:10%">Info</th>
                <th style="display:none">Functional Owner</th>
                <th style="display:none">Developed In</th>
                <th style="display:none">Category</th>
                <th style="display:none">Validation Assessment</th>
                <th style="display:none">Implementation Plan</th>
                <th style="display:none">Implementation Report</th>
                <th style="display:none">Intended Use</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Scrap Report</td>
                <td>Validated</td>
                <td>Business Objects</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Open</a></td>
                <td>(i)</td>
                <td style="display:none">Ops</td>
                <td style="display:none">Spotfire</td>
                <td style="display:none">Scrap</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">The intended use of this report is to identify the Scrap Cost by Reason at manufacturing processing steps by part number and date range. This data could be used to determine where process improvements can be made; and used for PFMEA calculations and PRB decisions/documentation.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Training xReport</td>
                <td>Validated</td>
                <td>Business Objects</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Open</a></td>
                <td>(i)</td>
                <td style="display:none">Ops</td>
                <td style="display:none">Spotfire</td>
                <td style="display:none">Scrap</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">The intended use of this report is to identify the Scrap Cost by Reason at manufacturing processing steps by part number and date range. This data could be used to determine where process improvements can be made; and used for PFMEA calculations and PRB decisions/documentation.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rty Report</td>
                <td>Validated</td>
                <td>Business Objectszzz</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Open</a></td>
                <td>(i)</td>
                <td style="display:none">Ops</td>
                <td style="display:none">Spotfire</td>
                <td style="display:none">Scrap</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">R12345</td>
                <td style="display:none">kalam</td>
                <td style="display:none">The intended use of this report is to identify the Scrap Cost by Reason at manufacturing processing steps by part number and date range. This data could be used to determine where process improvements can be made; and used for PFMEA calculations and PRB decisions/documentation.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, ii;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr:not(.header)");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            var tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            var found = false;
            for (ii = 0; ii < tds.length && !found; ii++) {
                if (tds[ii].textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            tr[i].style.display = found?"":"none";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: do not forgot to accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: I'm sorry, how do I do that? i am new to this site and can't find how to mark answered.

Comment: you will see a right sign next to up vote and down vote button just click it once and it will turn green.