# HTML Table Multiple Column Filters

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML table having three columns - (Name, Age, City). I'm trying to achieve 'MS Excel' like functionality, where I can filter multiple columns.

Although the filters are working individually, they malfunction when the user enters text in multiple input fields at once. For example, just entering the name would work fine, but entering the name along with the city, will completely rule out the name filter.

```js
function nameSearch() {
  var input_name, input_age, input_city, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue_name, txtValue_age, txtValue_city;

  input_name = document.getElementById("name-search");
  input_age = document.getElementById("age-search");
  input_city = document.getElementById("city-search");

  filter_name = input_name.value.toUpperCase();
  filter_age = input_age.value.toUpperCase();
  filter_city = input_city.value.toUpperCase();


  table = document.getElementById("custom-table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td_name = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td_name) {
      txtValue_name = td_name.textContent || td_name.innerText;
      if (txtValue_name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_name) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }

    }
  }
}

function ageSearch() {
  var input_name, input_age, input_city, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue_name, txtValue_age, txtValue_city;

  input_name = document.getElementById("name-search");
  input_age = document.getElementById("age-search");
  input_city = document.getElementById("city-search");

  filter_name = input_name.value.toUpperCase();
  filter_age = input_age.value.toUpperCase();
  filter_city = input_city.value.toUpperCase();


  table = document.getElementById("custom-table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td_age = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td_age) {
      txtValue_age = td_age.textContent || td_age.innerText;
      if (txtValue_age.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_age) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }

    }
  }
}

function citySearch() {
  var input_name, input_age, input_city, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue_name, txtValue_age, txtValue_city;

  input_name = document.getElementById("name-search");
  input_age = document.getElementById("age-search");
  input_city = document.getElementById("city-search");

  filter_name = input_name.value.toUpperCase();
  filter_age = input_age.value.toUpperCase();
  filter_city = input_city.value.toUpperCase();


  table = document.getElementById("custom-table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td_city = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    if (td_city) {
      txtValue_city = td_city.textContent || td_city.innerText;
      if (txtValue_city.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_city) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }

    }
  }
}
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="name-search" onkeyup="nameSearch()" placeholder="Name.." class="table-search-filters">
  <input type="text" id="age-search" onkeyup="ageSearch()" placeholder="Age.." class="table-search-filters">
  <input type="text" id="city-search" onkeyup="citySearch()" placeholder="City.." class="table-search-filters">
  <table id="custom-table">
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Bruce</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>Gotham</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bane</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>Chicago</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Joker</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>Gotham</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Harvey</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>Miami</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Instead of having three seperate 'onkeyup' function, I also tried to map all the inputs to a single function, but that still didn't help much.

Comment: Well, I think, you need a kinda source values list and visible values list. The source one is an input to your main filter function which returns a subset of the list (visible values). You should always apply all filters to your source list. Keyup event listeners should only change params for that filters.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what do you mean by source values list?

Comment: FYI: instead of `onkeyup` you probably want to use `oninput`. As it is now if I copy and paste text using the mouse it won't filter since no keys were pressed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering table multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622127/filtering-table-multiple-columns)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Unfortunately it doesn't because, that answer is using one input filter across multiple columns whereas I'm looking for multiple column filter using several input fields.

Comment: @gman Nice point. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Just curious, for the answer labelled as the solution, how do you make it not filter the header?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need of separate onKeyUp handlers for each input.Just one handler is enough.

Instead of getting elements by tag "td" `tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")`, use `tr[i].cells`

and `table.rows` to get rows (From gman's comment)

instead of  `tr =table.getElementsByTagName("tr");`

```
      tr = table.rows;
      for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td= tr[i].cells;
        td_name =td[0].innerText;
        td_age = td[1].innerText;
        td_city = td[2].innerText;
          if (td_name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_name) > -1 && td_age.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_age) > -1 && td_city.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_city) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } 
          else 
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
```

```js
var input_name = document.getElementById("name-search");
var input_age = document.getElementById("age-search");
var input_city = document.getElementById("city-search");
var table = document.getElementById("custom-table");

function search() {
  let filter_name = input_name.value.toUpperCase();
  let filter_age = input_age.value.toUpperCase();
  let filter_city = input_city.value.toUpperCase();
  let tr = table.rows;
  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].cells;
    td_name = td[0].innerText;
    td_age = td[1].innerText;
    td_city = td[2].innerText;
    if (td_name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_name) > -1 && td_age.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_age) > -1 && td_city.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_city) > -1) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="name-search" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Name.." class="table-search-filters">
  <input type="text" id="age-search" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Age.." class="table-search-filters">
  <input type="text" id="city-search" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="City.." class="table-search-filters">
  <table id="custom-table">
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Bruce</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>Gotham</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bane</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>Chicago</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Joker</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>Gotham</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Harvey</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>Miami</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this worked wonderfully. Could you please explain why instead of 'td' you are using tr[i].cells?

Comment: we can use both but instead of calling getElementsByTagName and other stuff we have a direct property on the row ,we can use row.cells

Comment: how we can use country name in a option to filter instead of a alphabet? Also Can I apply filter to other columns?

Comment: I got this working for me, any way to make this not start at the header row? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your three function into one and just check conditions with and(&&). hope below code helps.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
        <input type="text" id="name-search" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Name.." class="table-search-filters">
        <input type="text" id="age-search" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Age.." class="table-search-filters">
         <input type="text" id="city-search" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="City.." class="table-search-filters">
    <table id="custom-table">
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruce</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>Gotham</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bane</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>Chicago</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Joker</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>Gotham</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Harvey</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>Miami</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function search() {
    var input_name, input_age, input_city, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue_name, txtValue_age, txtValue_city;

    input_name = document.getElementById("name-search");
    input_age = document.getElementById("age-search");
    input_city = document.getElementById("city-search");

    filter_name = input_name.value.toUpperCase();
    filter_age = input_age.value.toUpperCase();
    filter_city = input_city.value.toUpperCase();


    table = document.getElementById("custom-table");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td_city = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
        td_age = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
        td_name = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

        if(td_city && td_age && td_name){
            txtValue_city = td_city.textContent || td_city.innerText;
            txtValue_age = td_age.textContent || td_age.innerText;
            txtValue_name = td_name.textContent || td_name.innerText;

            if (txtValue_city.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_city) > -1
                && txtValue_age.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_age) > -1
                && txtValue_name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_name) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            }
            else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, I missed that (&&) condition. I've accepted Supercool's answer here, as he/she answered first. Your solution is working as well :)

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to create a filtering function for each filter. You can use `startsWith`, `includes` or `===` to achieve a different searching behaviours.

Next, you need to create a "main" filter which will call all other filters.

Then add an event listener to the parent element (in my snipped I added it to the `window` object) to prevent multiple event listeners. When event occurs check it's target and call main filter function it it's needed.

Some obvious features:

- custom filtering behavious
- pure functions which can be easily tested
- composable main filter function
- no imperative mess =) (debatable)

```js
const sourceList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr"));

const nameFilter = (value, item) => !value || item.querySelector("td:nth-child(1)").textContent.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());

const ageFilter = (value, item) => !value || item.querySelector("td:nth-child(2)").textContent.startsWith(value);

const cityFilter = (value, item) => !value || item.querySelector("td:nth-child(3)").textContent.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());

const mainFilter = ({name, age, city}, item) => {
  return nameFilter(name, item) && ageFilter(age, item) && cityFilter(city, item);
}

const currentFilters = {
  name: '',
  age: '',
  city: '',
};

window.addEventListener('input', event => {
  if (event.target.matches('.table-search-filters')) {
  
    currentFilters[event.target.name] = event.target.value;   
    sourceList.forEach(item => {
      const isVisible = mainFilter(currentFilters, item);

      item.style.display = !isVisible ? 'none' : 'inherit';
    })
  }

})

const table = document.querySelector('table');
```

```html
<input name="name" type="text" id="name-search" placeholder="Name.." class="table-search-filters">
<input name="age" type="text" id="age-search" placeholder="Age.." class="table-search-filters">
<input name="city" type="text" id="city-search" placeholder="City.." class="table-search-filters">
    <table id="custom-table">
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruce</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>Gotham</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bane</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>Chicago</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Joker</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>Gotham</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Harvey</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>Miami</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the filters don't seem to work in the above code. Example - On searching 'bruce' the results are blank

Comment: sure, I didn't add lowering case func =)

Comment: @RohitGirdhar check this out, I've updated the code. Now it lowers all text elements and matches them.

Comment: If b is selected in column 1, then type in g for city column, Gotham will not be selected.

Comment: @Davesexcel as you can see I used the `.includes` method there. Since "Chicago" has a "g" letter in it, it is displayed pretty reasonably.

You can change the method to `.startsWith` and get a desired behaviour.

Comment: Ha!, I didn't even think of Chicago had the g as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a header change  to include class = header or change  to

```
<tr class="header">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>City</th>
</tr>
```

inside

and use this line of code in *.js file

`tr = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr:not(.header)");`

[table header missing after search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968177/table-header-missing-after-search)