Monitor changes to number of visible rows in an HTML table
I currently count the number of visible rows in an HTML table, before and after applying a search. This count is placed into a textbox by an onclick event of the button "results".
Is it possible to call a callback function when there's a change in the number of visible rows, as to update the text box immediately?
HTML:
<button type="button" class="rst" onclick="countFunction()">results</button>
<input type="text" id="textbox">


Instead of putting the word "solved" in the title, mark the answer that helped you with an acceptance mark.

You can use a MutationObserver to monitor changes to the tbody element and then check the number of visible rows. The one quirk here is that CSS changes can't be checked, so I used an HTML attribute to represent visibility which will be monitored by the observer.


const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody")
const rowCount = document.querySelector("#rowcount")

function updateRowCount() {
  const rows = new Set(tbody.querySelectorAll("tr"))
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    if (row.getAttribute("visibility") == "hidden") {
      rows.delete(row)
    }
  })
  rowCount.textContent = rows.size
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(() => updateRowCount());

observer.observe(tbody, {
  subtree: true,
  childList: true,
  attributes: true
});

updateRowCount()

setTimeout(() => {
  const row = document.createElement("tr")
  const data = document.createElement("td")
  data.textContent = "row 3"
  row.appendChild(data)
  tbody.appendChild(row)
}, 3000)

setTimeout(() => {
  tbody.querySelectorAll("tr")[0].removeAttribute("visibility")
}, 6000)
[visibility="hidden"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
<p>rows: <span id="rowcount"></span></p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr visibility="hidden"><td>row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Edit: Based on the code you provided, you need to call the countFunction() after the for loop.
Your code should be like this:
var input_name = document.getElementById("name-search");
function search() { 
  let filter_name = input_name.value.toUpperCase();
  let tr = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr:not(.header)");
  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) { 
    td = tr[i].cells; td_name = td[0].innerText; 
    if (td_name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_name) > -1 ) { 
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
  }
  countFunction();
}

I made a working sample here based on your code with some modifications and sample table (if you see console error in the snippet, click the Expand snippet button):


<input type="text" id="name-search">
<button type="button" onclick="search()">search</button>
<input type="text" id="textbox">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="header"><th>Fruits</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>apple</td></tr>
    <tr><td>orange</td></tr>
    <tr><td>banana</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function countFunction() {
    var box = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    var w = $('tr:visible').length-1;
    textbox.value = w;
  }
  
  var input_name = document.getElementById("name-search");
  
  function search() {
    let filter_name = input_name.value.toUpperCase();
    let tr = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr:not(.header)");
    for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].cells;
      td_name = td[0].innerText;
      if (td_name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_name) > -1 ) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else tr[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    countFunction();
  }
</script>




Sorry, my code is:  function countFunction() {var box = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
var w = $('tr:visible').length-1;
textbox.value = w; }
Your suggestion looks very good, I will try it a little later.

I realize that I cannot apply your code (5 table rows) to my table of over 4000 rows. Can the code be changed to avoid listing each td?

Yes but can you share your whole JS code so we can check which one to modify? You can edit your question to add the JS code.

My code only searches for table rows that match the query, hiding those that do not. I only want to count the matching (visible) rows, getting the results into the textbox. As I said, this works if I attach an onclick bit to the textbox, but it would be nice to avoid the "onclick" part. The code is taken from the first answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61189530/html-table-multiple-column-filters, and there is little point in repeating it here.

@MichaelHerdman can you provide your JS search function? The one that hides the rows that don't match. That's what we need to modify to automatically count the visible rows. You may edit your question and add the function there. Thanks.

I am not sure which JS code you need, maybe this is it. html: results
 followed by:     function countFunction() {
var box = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
var w = $('tr:visible').length-1;
textbox.value = w;
}

@MichaelHerdman the function that searches for rows that match the query

The function, abbreviated to show only the first column:
var input_name = document.getElementById("name-search");
function search() {
let filter_name = input_name.value.toUpperCase();
let tr = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr:not(.header)");
for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
td = tr[i].cells;
td_name = td[0].innerText;
if (td_name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter_name) > -1 ) {
tr[i].style.display = "";
} else
tr[i].style.display = "none";
}
}

@MichaelHerdman I already modified my answer based on your code. Kindly check. You can directly call the countFunction() after the for loop.

Thanks for trying, but that does not enter the results (row counts) into the textbox. I guess I have to stay with the onclick method - not very nice to ask the user to do many times, but it does work. In addition, I now have a stray "}" which appears on the page, and I cannot see how to remove it.

Edit. I got rid of the stray "}". After calling the function after the for loop as you suggest, I get the total row count in the checkbox, but  after searching the count does not change: function countFunction() {
var a = document.getElementById("data_table");
var box = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
var y = $('tr:visible').length-1;
textbox.value = y;
}  How can it be done?

@MichaelHerdman  see my edits. I added a working sample. You can use it as reference. So the first input box is for the search. Type there and click search and the second input box will have count of rows.

Superb! Thank you so much, Christian.

put me on the right track with this. We had a long discussion about placing the number of records matching a query (visible tr) into a textbox. The answer worked as well as expected (10 results, textbox reading 10). However, on removing the search term, although the full table is restored, the textbox display stays at 10. Is there an onchange statement that will reset that value to match the changed table?

Yes, you can add ‘onkeypress="search()"’ on your search input. It should be like this: ‘ <input type="text" id="name-search" onkeypress="search() >’ . Although it will also search automatically the table upon keypress so you no longer need search button.

That works very well, thank you yet again!

Edit: your change does work very well providing I delete manually the search term. However, I have 15 columns, each with a textbox, and often use 4 or more simultaneously. Manual deletion is possible, but easier by clicking a "reset" button I added: 
The rest of the code exceeds the limit on length of comments, and will have to follow this (as a single or split into several comments).

Part 1 of code:   function {
var input, textbox, filter, table, tr, td, i, xtValue;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
filter = clear ? "" : input.value.toUpperCase();
table = document.getElementById("data_table");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

Part 2 of code, join to part 1:
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
if (td) {
txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
tr[i].style.display = "";
} else {
tr[i].style.display = "none";
}
}
}
}
